# Extending an Enum by copying

Tags: java, enums

I wish to "extend" enum XResult in enum XStatus, by copying the values of XResult into XStatus.

Here is how I'm doing it. If item is not found in XResult, description is left null:

```
private final String description;
private final Whatever funStuff;

private XStatus(){
  String d=null;
  Whatever f=null;
  try{
    XResult xResult =  XResult.valueOf(this.name());
    d = XResult.toString();
    f = XResult.getWhatever();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  }

  this.description = d;
  this.funStuff = f;
}
```

The issue is that if XResult does not contain such an item, it would throw IllegalArgumentException.

**Question**:

- Is this the best way to copy values of one enum into another? The reason for the question is, I am deeply troubled with having the expense of try-catch to define the enum.
- Is the try-catch worthwhile for its expense, if indeed this is the only way.

What are my alternatives, besides unreliable manual copying (which does not track changes in XResult)?

**Rest of the code**:
For the curious, this is the rest of the code that is inconsequential to the question:

```
private XStatus(final String d){
  this.description = d;
}


public String toString(){
  if (description==null || description.length()==0)
    return doSomethingTo( this.name() );

  return description;
}

public getWhatever(){ /*similar to toString */ }
```

Comment: Enums are meant to be static. Use an actual class.

Comment: I can't use an actual class because XResult cannot be changed.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Enums cannot be extended because they are ordered, not because they are meant to be "static". Making enums extendable would confuse the ordering. Java should provide another "enum" which is unordered, called say, Category.

Comment: "Your code makes no sense" - if you understand how enums are instantiated, you would immediately understand the code, and the issue.

Comment: Or maybe we could call it a `class`? Also, `enum`s are not instantiated.

Comment: XStatus is the new enum.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes they are. What do you actually mean?

Comment: Could you add a common interface to `XResult` and `XStatus`, use a factory to get your instance and then just program to that interface?

Comment: I am not allowed to change XResult.

Comment: "Also, enums are not instantiated" - What ??? It is allowed private constructor. An instance of enum exists when an enum value is declared. In principle and in theory, "instantiating" is the act of creating an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, enums are in principle just Java objects so you could use reflection to test if XResult contains the desired value or even [add new values at runtime](http://www.jroller.com/VelkaVrana/entry/modify_enum_with_reflection) to your enum class.

Comment: I love your answer, BUT ... reflection is more expensive than try-catch.

Comment: if reflection is to expensive and you want to avoid try-catch statements you probably have to modify the XResult enum class definition upon loading - using a classloader and a byte-manipulation library like f.e. [javassit](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). Other than that I do not see a better way as to deal with the exception - especially as you are not allowed to modify XResult

Comment: Care to provide another answer to elaborate on your interesting alternative? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, and in case someone suggests this as answer, my initial way was to do it this way:

```
private final String description;
private final Whatever funStuff;

private XStatus(XResult xResult){
  this.description = xResult.toString();
  this.funStuff = xResult.getWhatever();
}
```

Which means, instead of declaring

```
enum XStatus {
  //from XResult
  NOT_FOUND,
  DELETED,
  PROCESSED,
  TBD,
  blah, blah ...

}
```

I would have to declare

```
enum XStatus {
  //from XResult
  NOT_FOUND(XResult.NOT_FOUND),
  DELETED(XResult.DELETED),
  PROCESSED(XResult.PROCESSED),
  TBD(XResult.TBD),
  blah, blah ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it without valueOf in generally O(1):

```
public enum XStatus {
    ;

    private XStatus() {
        XResult xr = Helper.NAMES.get(this.name()); // do whatever with
    }

    static {
        Helper.NAMES = null; // get rid of the map
    }                        // after the constants are instantiated

    private static class Helper {
        static Map<String, XResult> NAMES = new HashMap<String, XResult>();
        static {
            for(XResult xr : XResult.values()) {
                NAMES.put(xr.name(), xr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is basically the same as valueOf but you don't have to try-catch. Of course valueOf only throws RuntimeExceptions so you only have to catch if you have constants that do not parallel XResult.

Also, just throwing this out there, a more automatic solution would be something like this:

```
public final class XStatus {
    private XStatus(XResult xr) {
        //
    }

    private static final XStatus[] TABLE; // or an EnumMap
                                          // with Collections.unmodifiableMap
    static {
        XResult[] xrValues = XResult.values();
        TABLE = new XStatus[xrValues.length];

        for(XResult xr : xrValues) {
            TABLE[xr.ordinal()] = new XStatus(xr);
        }
    }

    public static XStatus xStatusFor(XResult xr) {
        return TABLE[xr.ordinal()];
    }
}
```

That will mirror XResult 1:1 without relying on any kind of String evaluation. You need an XResult to retrieve its corresponding constant but that's the point. Also if for some reason XResult were to change outside of your control you don't need to change XStatus.

Comment: You did not notice my other comments that I am not allowed the priv to change XResult. Also, I did not care to be accurate for parts of the code I simplified that were not the focus of the question, simply that they were not the focus of the question. Please edit your answer to remove the distraction to the other parts of the code, simply because the code to those parts are simplified.

Comment: Search by iteration is a very painful and expensive way, a favourite practice in novice Javascript programming. Especially thro a long list of items.

Comment: Behold, O(1) solution. Do you have 1000 constants or something?

Comment: Also I added a different solution that does not use Enum and is arguably more stable. IRT *"What are my alternatives, besides unreliable manual copying (which does not track changes in XResult)?"*

Answer (score 0):

A further technique which might solve your problem to dynamically change the XResult class on loading it to your application is to simply manipulate its content at load-time using a byte manipulation framework like f.e. [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

This requires however that your application hasn't loaded the enum before and you run your own classloader which will load the enum (and all the classes that access the enum) in that classloader (or in a child classloader of the classloader that loaded the bytes of the enum you have modified).

On using javassist you could do something like that (haven't done it actually with enums yet)

```
public byte[] modifyClass(String className)
{
    try
    {
        // load the bytes from the .class file that actually contains the original definition of the XResult enum
        byte[] xResultBytes = ...

        // define a classpool javassist will use to find the definition for classes
        ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
        // add a new search path for class definitions to the class path
        cp = cp.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass()));
        // add the jar file containing java classes needed to the classpath
        cp = cp.insertClassPath(jarFile.getAbsolutePath());
        // as you do not have loaded XResult with any classloader yet you do not have a Class file of it
        // so you need to provide the loaded bytes and the fully-qualified class name of the enum
        cp = cp.appendClassPath(new ByteArrayClassPath(className, xResultBytes));

        // now you are good to go with modifying the class

        // first create a javassist classrepresentation of the bytes loaded
        CtClass cc = cp.get(className);
        // you can't modify frozen classes
        if (!cc.isFrozen())
        {
            // you only want to instrument the XResult.class
            if (className.endsWith("XResult")) // better replace it with the full name
            {
                // find, add, remove or rename annotations, fields and methods to your liking here
            }
        }

        return cc.toBytecode();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

In a custom classloader you can override `findClass` to actually define the modified bytes as XResult instead of the original bytes:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    // instead of using the original bytes use the modified byte of the class
    byte[] classBytes = modifyClass(className);
    if (classBytes != null)
    {
        // this will actually create the Class<XResult> enum representation
        return defineClass(className, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
    }
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(...);
}
```

Instead of a custom classloader you could also use the loader javassist provides:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
 Loader cl = new Loader(pool);

 CtClass ct = pool.get("test.Rectangle");
 ct.setSuperclass(pool.get("test.Point"));

 Class c = cl.loadClass("test.Rectangle");
 Object rect = c.newInstance();
```

Probably you should decompile an enum class and see what an enum class actually contains and what part is you want to get rid of. F.e if the thrown exception does bother you you could simply remove the method and replace it with one that don't throws the exception but returns simply null.

Have a look at the very explanatory tutorials javassist have:

- [Reading and writing bytecode, ClassPool, ClassLoader](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html)
- [Introspection and customization](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html)
- [Bytecode level API, Generics, Varargs, J2ME](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: My project architect and leader would kill me for using this. Highly probable not allowed in corp framework. Would you think I could use Guice to reflectively inject? If yes, yet another answer please?

Comment: This is the point where I have to pass - no experiences with guice yet